# Explain strange Dispatcher behavior (a hidden WPF feature)

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have a window with a single button within.

The code-behind is

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Button ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Thread w = new Thread((ThreadStart) Worker);
    w.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  // removing/adding this doesn't make effect
    w.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("Direct");
}

void Worker()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Worker ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                               {
                                   Trace.TraceInformation("Invoked ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                   MessageBox.Show("Invoked");
                               });
}
```

Clicking the button results in **2** message boxes.

At the same time, trace shows same numbers for *Button ThreadId* and *Invoked ThreadId*.

Comment: Then the worker is running on the main thread? Check this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() to see if an invoke was even necessary.

Comment: This example is artificial. I've created it to possibly catch my misunderstanding.

Comment: MessageBox.Show() is a blocking call. That is, Button_Click does not exit before I click on the "Direct" message box. I've experimented by placing Trace.TraceInformation() before and after each message box.

Comment: Button_Click is called by XAML correspondent. A similar question is: which dispatcher should I use to make "Invoked" message box appear after I dismiss "Direct" one.

Answer (score 2):

The Dispatcher always carries out work on the GUI thread. That is why your ThreadId's match up. You are asking the GUI thread- "what's your ThreadId?" and then performing some work through the Dispatcher, which is again going to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a walk I understood what was happening.

Here is my <strike>explanation</strike> idea what's wrong with the code (or the reason the question was posted).

`Button_Click` is executed in the `Dispatcher` thread. The `Dispatcher` thread, as I know, is a single one for a window and its children.

Even if `Button_Click` takes more than a second (long enough), and user manages to click the button again (or somehow else interact with UI), the next `Button_Click` (or other appropriate handler) is not executed immediately, but placed in the *dispatching* queue.

`Dispatcher.Invoke` executes a delegate in the UI thread. `Invoke`, I suppose, sends a message to the delegate `GetMessage()` loop and blocks the calling thread till the message completes.

I expected the delegate to begin execution **only after** `Button_Click` exits.

`MessageBox.Show()` is a blocking call. Next statement won't be executed before the user clicks 'Ok'.

What is actually happening is the Dispatcher actually distinguishes between different windows and knows that `Button_Click` has called a modal dialog and therefore any interaction with the window should produce a beep and the message box should flash.

But is *goes on* dispatching messages. After all, this why all user clicks are translated into Button.Click messages and the message box gets closed.

This is why the invoked delegate is executed **before** `Button_Click` exits. 
The invoked delegate **breaks into** the `Button_Click`.

P.S. As you see in the code, the delegate also calls `MessageBox.Show()`. This leads to a new message box **which is modal** to the previous one. I noted I cannot click 'Ok' on the "Direct" msgBox before "Invoked" one.

Comment: Sort of.  You are close. Read this article very carefully. It explains most everything you are trying to experiment to figure out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

Comment: Bingo! The feature is called 'nested loops'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this WPF Dispatcher stuff so downvote me if I am totally wrong, but it looks like your call to *this.Dispatcher* is really your Window's (UI thread) Dispatcher. Thus, any code will be executed by the UI thread, not your application instantiated thread.

[Edit]

Here is the console output I received from running the above code

```
DispatcherQuestion.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Button ThreadId: 9    // UI Thread
DispatcherQuestion.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Worker ThreadId: 11   // Thread w
DispatcherQuestion.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Invoked ThreadId: 9   // UI Thread
```

ThreadID 9 is the user interface thread. Your Button and your Invoke call are both being performed, as designed, by the UI thread.

I found [this article today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) on MSDN that really clarified things about the WPF Threading/Dispatcher model.

Comment: The first and last calls to ManagedThreadId are supposed to match.

Comment: It doesn't matter that he said this.Dispatcher. He could have used the Button Dispatcher or any other Control's Dispatcher. The Dispatcher executes on the UI thread- always.